# Why length of String from Android get SSID is not equal to String my define?

Tags: android

My code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
String ssid = wInfo.getSSID().toString();
String ppkwifi1=ssid;
String ppkwifi2 = "WiredSSID";
```

My pic:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0TZXrf985hlUHBDeHF4UWRtSXc
Result from ssid is "WiredSSID" same as ppkwifi2 but lenght of ppkwifi1 is 11,ppkwifi2 is 9. What's going on?

Comment: if i use in static it works ex.ppkwifi1 = "WiredSSID"; ppkwifi2="WiredSSID" it show length = 9 of both,but getvalue from ssid variable from network why shown 11?

Comment: I had the same problem. The OS adds double quotes at the beginning and the end of `wInfo.getSSID().toString()`. Try - `wInfo.getSSID().toString().replace("\"", "")`